# MDX Case statement

Tags: excel, mdx, powerpivot

I am trying to use a MDX calculated measure to do a case statement on a column.

I am using this code:

```
Case [hist].[title] when "Mr" then "Test1 "Else "Test2"end
```

when I save it it sets everything to Test2 in the new column even though Mr is in the title field for some of the record. Any ideas where I could be going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In mdx you can say:

```
CASE  
 WHEN [hist].[title].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION = "Mr"
    THEN "Test1"
 ELSE "Test2"
END
```

or

```
CASE  
 WHEN [hist].[title].CURRENTMEMBER 
     IS [hist].[title].[title].&[Mr]
    THEN "Test1"
 ELSE "Test2"
END
```

'IIF' is better to use as default:

```
IIF(  
 [hist].[title].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION = "Mr"
 ,"Test1"
 ,"Test2"
)
```

or

```
IIF(  
 [hist].[title].CURRENTMEMBER 
     IS [hist].[title].[title].&[Mr]
 ,"Test1"
 ,"Test2"
)
```

---

note

In terms of performance:
- `IS` operator is preferable to using `.MEMBER_CAPTION = "Mr"`
- `IIF` generally performs better than `CASE`
- If you can get away with one of the branches of `IIF` being `NULL` then chances are your calculation will run in the faster block mode.

So this would be best:

```
IIF(  
 [hist].[title].CURRENTMEMBER 
     IS [hist].[title].[title].&[Mr]
 ,"Test1"
 ,NULL
)
```

Comment: Thanks but when I try that I get the same result all records show test 2

Comment: @rory83 ok - my mistake - you either need to use the `MEMBER_CAPTION` property or better to us the `IS` operator and drag the exact member for "Mr" to the right of the operator - I will guess the full name.